# How to use my own custom session value in Wordpress?

Tags: session

How can i use my own (custom) session value in Wordpress?
For example: `$_SESSION['myname']="4lvin"`

I've already inserted `session_start()` at all page i need as following.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['myname'] = "4lvin";
?>
```

But not working Global-wise.
Just working on the self page.
It is NOT call-able Globally from another pages (using same logic).

Comment: Can you please clarify the **WordPress-specific** nature of your question?

Comment: What is WordPress-specific nature ?

Comment: "*What is WordPress-specific nature ?*" - that means, in what way is your question related to **WordPress**?

Comment: In what way is my question related to WordPress?? So, please read my question and you will understand what is relating to Wordpress.

Comment: I see a question about **session cookies**. I don't see anything specific to **WordPress**, which is why I asked for clarification.

Comment: Does **session** or **cookies** `NOT` relating to Wordpress?
(or) Does WordPress not using any of them ?

Comment: No. *Sessions* and *cookies* are general internet/web-browser topics toward which WordPress is entirely agnostic.

Comment: @Chip Bennett, So.. does WordPress is not having any problems (relating) with Sessions/Cookies ??? No one should ask about these problem for Wordpress ?????? Huh...? So I think you don't have enough experience with WordPress for these kinds of problems.

Comment: I would recommend [reading the WordPress StackExchange FAQ regarding scope of questions asked](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#questions).

Comment: Yes, sessions and cookies are general topics, but this is more a question of making sessions work with WordPress ... and since WP itself doesn't use sessions, it's relevant here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**EDIT:** "THE PLUGIN BELOW ISN'T AVAILABLE ANYMORE, SO PLEASE USE THAT PLUGIN INSTEAD: [WordPress Session Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-session-manager/)"

There is a good WordPress Plugin adapted from CodeIgniter Session class: [WP Sessions Plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-sessions-plugin-with-database/3405722).

When you activate the plugin, you can start to use `$session` object from anywhere in your theme (`$session` object as long as global). For instance, to use $session object into `header.php` file, simply add this code:

```
global $session;
```

> If you are a plugin developer and you want to adapt this plugin with yours, you can find *standalone version* in the package as well. Documentation of the plugin gives more information for plugin developers about how to adapt to your project.

Here is some useful functions for both theme and plugin developers.

You can **add** session data like this:

```
// One value
$session->set_userdata( 'username', 'john' );

// Passing array
$array = array(
    'username' => 'john',
    'email'    => 'john@gmail.com'
);

$session->set_userdata( $array );
```

To **retrieve** session data:

```
$session->userdata( 'username' );
```

To **get all** session data:

```
$session->all_userdata(); // returns array
```

To **remove** one item from session:

```
$session->unset_userdata( 'username' );
```

To **remove more items** from session:

```
$array = array(
    'username' => '',
    'email'    => ''
);
$session->unset_userdata( $array );
```

You can also use **Flashdata** which is session data that will only be available for the next server request, are then automatically cleared. These can be very useful when you use them for *informational* or *status messages* (e.g. “Product has been deleted”).

```
// Add Flashdata
$session->set_flashdata( 'item', 'value' );

// Retrieve Flashdata
$session->flashdata( 'item' );

// Preserving flashdata 
// (if you need to preserve flashdata through an additional request, 
// you can use this function):
$session->keep_flashdata( 'item' );
```

To destroy session:

```
$session->sess_destroy();
```

The plugin also supports **shortcodes**. You can print any session data on your posts or pages:

```
[session key="username"]
```

To reach second key:

```
[session key="user_data" sec_key="display_name"]
```

I hope this helps for someone.

Comment: WP Sessions Plugin is not there!??

Comment: Yes, you'll want to use that one: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-session-manager/ (This is much better and stabile).

Comment: Another plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-native-php-sessions/

Comment: Why can't we use PHP default session functionality in WordPress? This solution creates dependency on a plugin.

Comment: @Amritpal because not all PHP/Apache servers support sessions. If you want to build a public software/plugin like WP, you have to think about it. If its personal project where you are able to edit server, that's not a problem.

Answer (score 9):

WordPress doesn't use sessions, that's why your session variables aren't working.

As a matter of fact, if certain variables are defined, [WordPress will actually destroy `$_SESSION` to keep itself stateless](http://www.thinkingoutloud.co.za/content/20091012/php_wordpress_and_session).

But if you really want to use sessions, try adding `session_start()` at the beginning of your `wp-config.php` file.  This will (hopefully) start sessions whenever WP starts up, so you'll then be able to set and read your `$_SESSION` variables elsewhere in the system.

Comment: I saw that Wordpress uses Cookies to store some login data. When i printed $_COOKIE array, i could see some data. I would like to set that data manually. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21595900/how-to-bypass-wordpress-login

Comment: Also, is it recommended to modify the wp-config.php file, to start session ? If we update Wordpress later, does the wp-config.php file get updated too?

Comment: Tutorial that discusses this more http://silvermapleweb.com/using-the-php-session-in-wordpress/

Comment: @shasikanth no, `wp-cofnig.php` is not touched on updates.

Comment: @shasikanth `wp-config.php` will not get updated, otherwise you could lose you DB connection and other parameters you have manually set.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution without using plug-in or without modifying the `wp-config.php` is to update your theme's `functions.php` and insert at the very beginning the following:

```
<?php

 //WordPress functions.php file
  if(!session_id()) {           
    session_start();            
  }
```

Since the `functions.php` (or so called theme functions file) is a template included in WordPress themes automatically and acts **like a plugin** for your WordPress site.  Moreover, if you have more than 1 theme installed on your website, modifying the `functions.php` will affect only the chosen theme, not all (where you **may not** want to enable sessions).

Answer (score -3):

**Wordpress does support it**.
You need to add following lines at the top of `functions.php`

```
if ( ! session_id() ) {
    session_start();
}
```

Comment: Why would you start the session twice?