# Unique Transients user id for Non-Logged In users

Tags: transient

I am coding a plugin and it seems wordpress discourage use of Sessions. I have a kind of wizard for non-logged in users that asks for First Name, Last Name etc and some conditional questions from users in 4 different steps and then eventually registers user and shows his username/pass in last step.

I am stuck on this last step since I am not able to hold data in sessions. Should I even use Transients API to hold this kind of data? How can I make Transients data a non-logged in user specific? Don't want to use cookies or you think I must use cookies in this scenario?

Comment: What is wrong with sessions?

Comment: should I go for PHP sessions? It seems wordpress discourages use of session to keep itself stateless. Just trying to do things wordpress way and keep myself updated.

Answer (score 1):

Use sessions when they are appropriate.

Our fellow mod [@EAMann](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/46/eamann) has [written a useful session class](http://eamann.com/tech/introducing-wp_session/) for exactly these cases. There is a plugin [described here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72744/73) that offers a different API.

Just make sure to start the session only when you really need one. Google and other crawler don’t accept cookies, so you would end up with lots of duplicated URLs indexed like this:

```
/postname/?sid=123455667889
```