# Sessions with WordPress

Tags: php, session

I am implementing custom user registration system for website clients, so that they can edit their information. But I have read a lot that WordPress do not support session. For example, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/32658/124078

I have made a login panel and it is working fine. But I want to know what is correct way to use session or how can I make my own custom registration system with session and cookies

I am using session_start() and then store the details in session variable, but after reading a lot on WordPress sessions, that it is stateless and destroys the session. I want your opinion. I am confused, am I doing it right way?

Comment: WordPress doesn't use PHP sessions for logins, it uses cookies. A lot of hosts don't work with PHP sessions due to the way caching works. I'd strongly recommend using cookies yourself. You can also reuse WP's registration system with a custom login/registration, you don't have to use WP Admin

Comment: Could you please reference some links. It will be very kind. My need is to give my clients a page to login and register and if they login I will create a profile page.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You can write it as an answer.

Comment: Creating a custom login page, redirecting users on login to a specific page (e.g. a profile page), creating a registration page, etc, are all covered in other questions independently on the site, they'll answer it far better than I ever could